# Delay on javascript loading

Tags: javascript, svg, load, delay, mouseover

I'm new with javascript and I don't understand why the javascript file takes so long to load.

My page right now consists of a svg image file of a house, in which I've embedded several path objects. When I hover over a room, I'm using a javascript function on mouseover event of the path objects to highlight that room, changing the path's fill and opacity properties.

The script works fine and the rooms are highlighted as I wanted, but in order for the script functions to start working it takes several seconds (30 seconds or longer). Once the first room starts to be highlighted, the others work fast and smooth.

Is there something wrong with the javascript loading function?

I'm using this code line inside the svg file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="Script.js" xlink:actuate="onLoad" xlink:show="other" xlink:type="simple" />
```

I also tried to load the javascript file directly on the html file, but I ended up getting the same delay.

Comment: Can you show the actual javascript code? It could be something in there that it is having trouble processing

Comment: What have you tried to identify the problem?  Same delay in different browsers?  Errors in the dev console?  Timings in the dev console? More information or a working example would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about the late response.
The site is available on http://hemgtest.azurewebsites.net/. The hovering effect over the rooms is the one I can notice the delay on, and I don't get any errors on the dev console.
I've noticed that it takes way longer for the javascript function to load on Chrome than it does in Firefox.